# Updating a Firefox addon fails on some machines

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, rdf, updates

We have a Firefox addon which we host ourselves on our own secure (https) servers. Our addon always installs for the first time into a current version of Firefox without issue.  However, when a new version of the addon is published and the update mechanism of the Firefox Add-ons Manager is invoked, some of the updates will succeed and some will fail.

Thus far we have been unable to determine what is causing the random failures.  We are hoping that someone will be able to look at our information and be able to see something we have missed, and help us cure this problem.

**Here is our RDF file...**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:extension:jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack">
    <em:updates>
      <Seq>
        <li>
          <Description>
            <em:version>2.0.27</em:version>
            <em:targetApplication>
              <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>10.0</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>23.*</em:maxVersion>
               <em:updateLink>https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/livehive.xpi</em:updateLink>
              </Description>
            </em:targetApplication>
          </Description>
        </li>
      </Seq>
    </em:updates>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

**Here is the log output from one machine that failed to update...**

```
001 LOG addons.updates: Requesting https://versioncheck.addons.mozilla.org/update/VersionCheck.php?reqVersion=2&id={f13b157f-b174-47e7-a34d-4815ddfdfeb8}&version=0.9.89&maxAppVersion=14.0a1&status=userEnabled&appID={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}&appVersion=23.0.1&appOS=WINNT&appABI=x86-msvc&locale=en-US&currentAppVersion=23.0.1&updateType=97&compatMode=normal
002 LOG addons.updates: Requesting https://versioncheck.addons.mozilla.org/update/VersionCheck.php?reqVersion=2&id=jid0-GXjLLfbCoAx0LcltEdFrEkQdQPI@jetpack&version=2.4.0.1&maxAppVersion=20.*&status=userEnabled&appID={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}&appVersion=23.0.1&appOS=WINNT&appABI=x86-msvc&locale=en-US&currentAppVersion=23.0.1&updateType=97&compatMode=normal
003 LOG addons.updates: Requesting https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/update_ff.rdf
004 LOG addons.updates: Found an update entry for jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack version 2.0.27
005 LOG addons.updates: Found an update entry for {f13b157f-b174-47e7-a34d-4815ddfdfeb8} version 0.9.89
006 LOG addons.updates: Found an update entry for jid0-GXjLLfbCoAx0LcltEdFrEkQdQPI@jetpack version 2.4.0.1
007 LOG addons.xpi: Download started for https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/livehive.xpi to file C:\Users\dstod\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-i1t.xpi
008 LOG addons.xpi: Download of https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/livehive.xpi completed.
009 LOG addons.repository: Requesting https://services.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/api/1.5/search/guid:jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg%40jetpack?src=firefox&appOS=WINNT&appVersion=23.0.1
010 LOG addons.xpi: Starting install of https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/livehive.xpi
011 LOG addons.xpi: Addon jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack will be installed as a packed xpi
012 LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method shutdown on jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack version 2.0.23
013 Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome.manifest'.
014 Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/extensions/%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D/chrome.manifest'.
015 LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method uninstall on jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack version 2.0.23
016 LOG addons.xpi: Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Users\dstod\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\f1hj0mzi.default\extensions\jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack.xpi
017 LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method install on jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack version 2.0.23
018 LOG addons.xpi: Install of https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/livehive.xpi completed.
019 LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method startup on jid1-aWPVzAyllHmjZg@jetpack version 2.0.23
```

In this case we were upgrading from version 2.0.23 to version 2.0.27.  Note in the log how the correct RDF file is located (line 3), the new version is correctly identified (line 4), and the new .XPI file is successfully downloaded (line 8).  Then the older version 2.0.23 is shutdown (line 12), and uninstalled (line 15).

It is here that something appears to go wrong: rather than installing version 2.0.27 which has been downloaded, version 2.0.23 is instead restarted again (lines 17-19) thus thwarting the update.  No error is logged, and no clue is given as to why this strange behavior has taken place.

Can anyone shed any light on what may be happening here?

Comment: Since there is no additional error, my bet would be on the browser still having cached https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/livehive.xpi. Try using no-cache headers or better cache validators or have unique URIs for each version of your XPI.

Comment: Your suggestion turned out to be the answer!  We changed the URL for the XPI to include the version number to make it unique and the problem disappeared.  Thanks for the suggestion.  How can I give you credit for the answer inside of a comment?

Comment: Made comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no additional error, it is likely that the browser still has your XPI in the cache and therefore does not download the new file.

Try using `no-cache` headers or better cache validators and/or have unique URIs for each version of your XPI.

Comment: To be clear, we used this information to solve the problem by creating unique URLs for each version of the add-on. This required two relatively simple changes to our process (1) creation of a new directory into which the new XPI was placed, and (2) a one line change in the RDF file.  Specifically for our latest version 2.0.27 the URL was changed to https://livehiveapp.com/product/extensions/ff/2027/livehive.xpi. The problem immediately disappeared from all previously failing machines.